# EditText no more than x decimals android

Tags: android

I have a EditText where I enter a number.

What I want is to forbid this number to have more than "x" number of decimals, for example, three.

I have tried to do it by using the listener, but I don´t find exactly the solution.......

```
precioProducto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    String[] numeroDecimal = s.toString().split(",");
                    if(numeroDecimal[1].length()==3){

                    }
                }
            });
```

How can i "lock" the EditText to be more than 3 decimals??

Thanks a lot.

---

I tried what Vinay Wadhwa told me, but after trying a little bit and so on, sometimes(not everytimes), the application breaks giving me the next log:

> 09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586): java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:103)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:283)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.(DynamicLayout.java:169)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6318)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6216)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6744)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3306)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at es.wul4.zarko.CrearPedidos$25.onTextChanged(CrearPedidos.java:686)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7634)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3309)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
>   09-07 11:37:32.119: E/AndroidRuntime(14586):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:

I don´t know why is giving me this problem, not even everytimes.......just sometimes after "touching" too many times the text inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class variable which stores the last previous value of the edit text

say `String lastVal`

```
 precioProducto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                      

                        String[] numeroDecimal = s.toString().split(",");
                        if(numeroDecimal[1].length()>=3){
                          precioProducto.setText(lastVal);
                        }
                        lastVal=s.toString();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please add below in EditText in your XML file.

```
android:maxLength="3"
```

Comment: I know that´s to forbid the number to have more than 3 characters, but it is not forbidding it to have more than 3 decimals(this way I can´t write "1000" either, which is a number without any decimal). Thanks anyway!