# Allow only two decimal input EditText

Tags: android

I need the EditText allow only seven integer and two decimal numbers. Ex: 7777777.99

I try with this Regex, in onTouchListener event, but not working. By the way, this is the correct event to do this??

```
txtRespNumero.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                   int count = 0;    // Declare as Instance Variable
                   boolean isSeven = true; // Declare as Instance Variable

                          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

                                count++;

                          }

                          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {


                          }

                          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                          if(isSeven){
                              if(count == 7){

                                  s.append(".");
                                  isSeven = true;
                              }
                           }

                           if(count < 7){

                               isSeven = true;

                           }

                          }
                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way...

**-** Set the `EditText` Attribute `Max Length` as 10.

**-** Then when you accept the `EditeText` value, convert it into format of 0000000.00 using the below example:

**Eg:**

```
double d = 300.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000000.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

**/////////////////////////////////// Edited Part /////////////////////////////**

Another way to do it, just as you want it.........

```
int count = 0;    // Declare as Instance Variable
boolean isSix = true; // Declare as Instance Variable

tx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CheckIt);

        tx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                  count++;

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(isSeven){
                if(count == 7){

                    s.append(".");
                    isSeven = true;
                }
             }

             if(count < 7){

                 isSeven = true;

             }

            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Declare as Instance Variable" ?? The IDE says----> "The final local variable isSeven cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

Comment: Kumar Vivek Mitra, See the Up please

Answer (score 0):

Try the onTextChanged rather, it get called everytime the user enters a numer (In your case) instead of only once when the control is touched). This solution worked for me:
[EditText no more than x decimals android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299414/edittext-no-more-than-x-decimals-android)

It is a pity that android does not allow you do this directly in the XML though.

Comment: I try with that solution, but the app is error and close when input the first number... See the question update Up...